# filter string only contains q in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

I need help in mysql query, i written this query

```
select * from post where content REGEXP '^q'
```

this query is working but it also includes spaces in filter, what i want to do if any content string like `"qqqqqq"` or `"qqqq"` or `"qqq"` or `"qq"` or `"q"` for this string only it should have to filter, right now what is happening if i have string like `"qqqq qq"`  then also it is giving me the result, it should not consider that space, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Your expression is only "starts with q" (basically identical to `where content like 'q%'`). What are your exact specs?

Comment: What about q*? ^q states that the match must begin with q's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your regexp like next:

```
select * from post where content REGEXP '^q+$';
```

This regular expression mean the string starts with `q` and contain only 1 or more `q` symbols till end of string

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=af0d839d548062535c43fd3003de36ba&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this **^q+(?![\s])+$** Regular Expression.

Above RegExp will check for string starting with q and without space.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regex for this. String functions are likely to be more efficient. You can replace all "q"s with empty strings, and ensure that that resulting string is empty:

```
select * from post where replace(content, 'q', '') = ''
```

Note that this also allows the empty string. If you want to avoid that, then:

```
select * from post where content <> '' and replace(content, 'q', '') = ''
```